# How do I add in a new Activity Type for CiviCampaign?

Tags: civicampaign

How do I add in a new Activity Type for CiviCampaign?

I can see how to do this via  CiviCRM » Administer CiviCRM » Option Groups  » Activity Type Options for Contacts only.

Any help would be great!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? Do you mean adding a campaing type? You do not specifically specify an activity type for a campaign, you can add an activity to a campaign?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that anymore through the user interface. In previous versions of CiviCRM you could define the activity for contacts and cases, or cases.

As Erik said, any activity could be linked to a campaign, there is no restriction on that. So there is no need to to define whether you want use an activity only in campaigns.